# Button won't show up in the table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UIButton subclass which customizes a button. Then I have a UITableViewCell subclass which uses this button and position it in the cell. Finally I have a subclass of UITableViewController which displays the table view and contains the customized cell. My problem is that the customized button "starbtn" won't show up in the table, while everything else is working properly. What is wrong in my code?

**favButton.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface favButton : UIButton {
    BOOL    _checked;
}

@property (nonatomic, setter = setChecked:) BOOL checked;

-(void) setChecked:(BOOL) check;

@end
```

**favButton.m**

```
#import "favButton.h"

@implementation favButton

@synthesize checked = _checked;

-(id) init
{
    if( self=[super init] )
    {
        self.checked = NO;
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(OnCheck:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) awakeFromNib
{
    self.checked = NO;
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(OnCheck:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void) setChecked:(BOOL) check
{
    _checked = check;
    if( _checked )
    {
        [self setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"startbefore.jpg"];
        [self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];

    }
    else
    {
        [self setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"startafter.jpg"];
        [self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];

    }
}

-(void) OnCheck:(id) sender
{
    self.checked = !_checked;
}


@end
```

**imageCellCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "favButton.h"

    @interface imageCellCell : UITableViewCell 

    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label1;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label2;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *prodimage;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *thumbsup;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label3;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *basket;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *homebtn;

    @property (nonatomic, strong) favButton *starbtn;

    @end
```

**imageCellCell.m**

```
#import "imageCellCell.h"




@implementation imageCellCell

@synthesize view;
@synthesize label1;
@synthesize label2;
@synthesize prodimage;
@synthesize thumbsup;
@synthesize label3;
@synthesize basket;
@synthesize homebtn;
@synthesize starbtn;



- (instancetype)init {

    self = [super init];
    self.starbtn = [[favButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(243,0, 30, 30)];

    [starbtn setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 

    [starbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"startbefore.jpg"] 
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        [self addSubview:view];

        // initiate image
        prodimage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,2, 180, 180)];

        // initiate label1 score value
        label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230,80,150,20)];
        label1.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        [[self label1] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25]];


        // initiate label2 score label
        label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(232,50,150,20)];

        // initiate image
        thumbsup = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,108, 30, 30)];

        // initiate label3 manufacturer

        label3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90,200,180,20)];

        // initiate image
        basket = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280,1, 30, 30)];


        // initiate home button       
        homebtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4,0, 30, 30)];


        [homebtn setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
        [homebtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.jpg"]
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        [view addSubview:prodimage];
        [view addSubview:label1];
        [view addSubview:label2];
        [view addSubview:thumbsup];
        [view addSubview:label3];
        [view addSubview:basket];
        [view addSubview:homebtn];
        [view addSubview:starbtn];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**ProdViewController.m**

```
#import "ProdViewController.h"
#import "imageCellCell.h"


@interface ProdViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProdViewController
@synthesize tableview;
@synthesize tabbar;
@synthesize addfav;
@synthesize favData;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    favData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tableview setDataSource:self];
    [tableview setDelegate:self];


  }

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTableview:nil];
    [self setTabbar:nil];
    [self setAddfav:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}


...


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


NSString *CellIdentifier;
NSString *CellIdentifierimg;

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (cell == nil) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell = [[imageCellCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierimg];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }else if (indexPath.row == 4) {
                    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    }




    switch ([indexPath row])
    {
        case 0:
        {

            imageCellCell *firstRowCell = (imageCellCell *)cell;


            [firstRowCell.thumbsup  setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbs-up-green.jpg"]];

            [firstRowCell.prodimage  setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"test1.jpg"]];
            [firstRowCell.label1 setText:@"10"];
            [firstRowCell.label2 setText:@"Score"];
            [firstRowCell.label3 setText:@"Name"];

            [firstRowCell.basket  setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Basket.jpg"]];

            // reference of the home button to the buttonclick method

            [firstRowCell.homebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

            // reference of the favorites button to the buttonclick method

            [firstRowCell.starbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickFavButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];




            firstRowCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


            break;


        }
        case 1:
        {


                cell.textLabel.text = @"Row 2";
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            break;

        }

        case 2:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Row 3";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


            break;

        }

        case 3:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Row 4";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


            break;


        }

            }

    return cell;

}



-(IBAction)clickFavButton:(id)sender{

[favData addObject:@"productname"];



}



@end
```

Comment: see my new edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why u are adding the `starbtn` in init method, put that code in `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`

comment out entire `init` method

```
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
     self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
     if (self) {

    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    [self addSubview:view];

    // initiate image
    prodimage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,2, 180, 180)];

    // initiate label1 score value
    label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230,80,150,20)];
    label1.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    [[self label1] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25]];


    // initiate label2 score label
    label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(232,50,150,20)];

    // initiate image
    thumbsup = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,108, 30, 30)];

    // initiate label3 manufacturer

    label3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90,200,180,20)];

    // initiate image
    basket = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280,1, 30, 30)];


    // initiate home button       
    homebtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4,0, 30, 30)];


    [homebtn setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
    [homebtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.jpg"]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     //initilise hear
     //edit
     starbtn = [[favButton alloc]init];
     starbtn.frame = CGRectMake(243,0, 30, 30)];
    //edit
     [starbtn setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 

     [starbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"startbefore.jpg"] 
                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [view addSubview: starbtn]; //add this

    [view addSubview:prodimage];
    [view addSubview:label1];
    [view addSubview:label2];
    [view addSubview:thumbsup];
    [view addSubview:label3];
    [view addSubview:basket];
    [view addSubview:homebtn];
    [view addSubview:starbtn];

 }
  return self;
}
```

**Edited Answer**

in your  `"favButton.h"` file

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  @interface favButton : UIButton
  {
     BOOL    _checked;
  }
  @property (nonatomic, setter = setChecked:) BOOL checked;
  -(void) setChecked:(BOOL) check;

  @end
```

in `"favButton.m"` file

```
 #import "favButton.h"

 @implementation favButton

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
  {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
          // Initialization code
          self.checked = NO;
          [self addTarget:self action:@selector(OnCheck:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      }
      return self;
   }

   -(void) awakeFromNib
    {
       self.checked = NO;
       [self addTarget:self action:@selector(OnCheck:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

   -(void) setChecked:(BOOL) check
   {
     _checked = check;
     if( _checked )
     {
      //  [self setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
          UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"22.jpg"];
      //        [self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"22.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      }
      else
      {
       // [self setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"33.jpg"];
       // [self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];
       [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"33.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }
   }

  -(void) OnCheck:(id) sender
  {
     self.checked = !_checked;
  } 


 /*
 // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
  // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
  {
    // Drawing code
  }
 */

 @end
```

in `imageCellCell.h` file

include only these methods

```
  - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
    // Initialization code
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        [self addSubview:view];

        // initiate image
        prodimage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,2, 180, 180)];

        // initiate label1 score value
        label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230,80,150,20)];
        label1.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        [[self label1] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25]];


        // initiate label2 score label
        label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(232,50,150,20)];

        // initiate image
        thumbsup = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,108, 30, 30)];

        // initiate label3 manufacturer

        label3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90,200,180,20)];

        // initiate image
        basket = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280,1, 30, 30)];


        // initiate home button
        homebtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4,0, 30, 30)];


        [homebtn setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [homebtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.jpg"]
                           forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        starbtn = [[favButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(243,0, 30, 30)];
        starbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
       // starbtn.frame = CGRectMake(243,0, 30, 30);

        //edit
        [starbtn setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [starbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"startbefore.jpg"]
                           forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [view addSubview: starbtn]; //add this

        [view addSubview:prodimage];
        [view addSubview:label1];
        [view addSubview:label2];
        [view addSubview:thumbsup];
        [view addSubview:label3];
        [view addSubview:basket];
        [view addSubview:homebtn];
        [view addSubview:starbtn];

    }
    return self;
  }

  - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
  {
     [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

     // Configure the view for the selected state
  }

  @end
```

in controller all are same no need to change

**End Edit**

Hope this helps u .. :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried it this way, but my customized button class makes uibutton act as a checkbox and determine the image displayed depending on wether it is selected. If I do it the way you are suggesting, the changes of the unbutton subclass in the images are not applied.

Comment: I have already included the btn to the SubView. It is not working. If I include this line [homebtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  it is like I am ignoring the subclass methods, so the images do not change properly on mouse click. But even if I remove it, it won't appear at all.

Comment: where u are adding this subclassed button in custom cell ... ?

Comment: and also wy u are using `- (instancetype)init` method to init the custom button

Comment: I add it at imageCellCell with [view addSubview:starbtn]; and initiate it with starbtn = [[favButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(243,0, 30, 30)];

Comment: I didn't make the custom button subclass, I took it from the web.

Comment: oky lets try the new edited answer i checked hear it is working fine for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57157/discussion-between-shan-and-user3211165).